# factorised polynomial congruence $f(x)=(x^2-7)*(x^2-11) \equiv 0 \mod p$ solvable for any p

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I want to prove that the congruence is solvable for any p, although $f$ has no root $\in Z[t]$
$$f(x)=(x^2-7)*(x^2-11) \equiv 0 \mod p$$
So far I thought about solving
$$x^2 \equiv 7 \,and\, x^2\equiv 11 \mod p$$ using the legendre symbols
$$(\frac{7}{p})\,and\, (\frac{11}{p}),$$
but I am stuck at this point already.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I maybe misunderstand you, but what is the solution for $p=13$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the law of quadratic reciprocity to compute the Legendre symbol. So
$$
\left( \frac{7}{13}\right)=\left( \frac{13}{7}\right)=\left( \frac{-1}{7}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}}=-1.
$$
We also have $\left( \frac{11}{13}\right)=-1$.

Comment: I see. If i alternated the $f(x)$ to e.g. $f(x)=(x^2-7)(x^2-11)(x^2-7*11)$ could i still use the same argument? Since there is another $7$ in the function.

Comment: We have $((7\cdot 11)/13)=(7/13)\cdot (11/13)=-1\cdot -1=+1$, so then it works.

Comment: In order to prove the claim for the new $f(x)$, i have to consider the two cases: $$p\equiv1\mod4 \,or\, p\equiv3\mod4$$, since $p$ can only be eigther one at a time.